# How to inspect Gradle CopySpec for exporting it to a text representation?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I use an application server's feature that allows me to deploy resources and classes directly from Gradle's output folders and static files from sources folders. I don't want to waste time for packaging to **EAR**, **WAR** or **JAR** and I want to use HotSwap-like features without redeploy.

Let me demonstrate the idea using a simple gradle project and Tomcat 7.

Assume we have a folder with the following structure:

```
.
|-- build.gradle
`-- src
    |-- css
    |   `-- main.css
    |-- html
    |   `-- index.html
    `-- images
        `-- logo.png

4 directories, 4 files
```

I create a simple gradle project:

*build.gradle*

```
apply plugin: 'war'

war {
  destinationDir temporaryDir
  into 'META-INF/resources', {
    from 'src/html/index.html'
  }
  into 'META-INF/resources/static', {
    from 'src/css'
  }
  into 'META-INF/resources/static', {
    from 'src/images'
  }
}
```

Then it would be perfect to have an ability for creating the following configuration automatically:

*$CATALINA_HOME/Catalina/localhost/myapp.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context docBase="">
  <Resources className="org.apache.naming.resources.VirtualDirContext" extraResourcePaths="
    /META-INF/resources/index.html=C:/myapp/src/html/index.html,
    /META-INF/resources/static=C:/myapp/src/css,
    /META-INF/resources/static=C:/myapp/src/images
  "/>
</Context>
```

Please notice it's not enough just create a list of files (without folder mapping) like:

```
/META-INF/resources/index.html=C:/myapp/src/html/index.html
/META-INF/resources/static/main.css=C:/myapp/src/css/main.css,
/META-INF/resources/static/logo.png=C:/myapp/src/images/logo.png
```

Because the original statement of problem means it is necessary to have a possibility to create and delete files in incoming folders without redeploy application.

#### Update 1

Created [issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1602) on Gradle's github

#### Update 2

Please notice that the example is just a fictional case to demonstrate you the idea. I know about the java sources path conventions.

My goal is to find an automatic way to generate a CopySpec map for existing large projects. I want to give an ability to any developer for adding and removing a CopySpec (or CopySpec-based task) without understanding the details how it's translated to application server's mapping config.

Answer (score 1):

Three approaches I can think of

1. Parse the groovy code into [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) and generate the xml from the AST. That sounds really difficult to me
2. Firstly define the directories etc in your own custom model. Then generate the `CopySpec` and the `XML` based on the same model. That sounds easier
3. Work your way through the internal Gradle API's (eg [War](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/tasks/bundling/War.java), [AbstractCopyTask](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/tasks/AbstractCopyTask.java) and [CopySpecInternal](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/file/copy/CopySpecInternal.java)) to see if you can do anything. Perhaps you can solve this with a [CopySpecVisitor](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/file/copy/CopySpecInternal.java#L62) or [CopySpecListener](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/file/copy/CopySpecInternal.java#L55). Note: If you use internal API's, Gradle makes no guarantee that it won't be broken in a future release.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eachFile` to record the parent directory of all the files that go into the war, and `doLast` to process your record and generate the XML you want.

For convenience I used Guava's `Multimap`, since the same virtual directory (in your app container) could map to multiple physical directories.

The following script prints to stdout, but you could easily change it to write to a file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories { jcenter() }
    dependencies { classpath 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0' }
}

import com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

apply plugin: 'war'

war {
    destinationDir temporaryDir
    into 'META-INF/resources', {
        from 'src/html/index.html'
    }
    into 'META-INF/resources/static', {
        from 'src/css'
    }
    into 'META-INF/resources/static', {
        from 'src/images'
    }

    def parentDirs = ArrayListMultimap.create()
    eachFile { file ->
        parentDirs.put(file.relativePath.parent, file.file.parent)
    }

    doLast {
        def lines = []
        for (e in parentDirs.entries()) {
           lines.add("$e.key=$e.value")
        }

        def writer = new StringWriter()
        def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
        xml.Context(docBase:"") {
            Resources(className:"org.apache.naming.resources.VirtualDirContext",
                extraResourcePaths:lines.join(","))
        }
        println writer
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in your example only directories were extracted to the map (not files). This is not what I need. Sometimes I don't want to add whole folder, just several files. For example, if I have `src/html/index_BAD.html`, it will be included as well.
And, second, this is a not declarative way. Imagine, we have a big multiproject with many Zip, Jar, War, Ear tasks. I wouldn't like to inject this code right to the existing tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you storing things in these non-standard locations? Why not use the Gradle (and Maven) convention? You could:

1. Move `src/html/index.html` to `src/main/webapp/META-INF/resources`
2. Move `src/css/*.*` to `src/main/webapp/META-INF/resources/static/*.*`
3. Move `src/images/*.*` to `src/main/webapp/META-INF/resources/static/*.*`
4. Remove the `into ... from ...` from the `war` config (since using the standard conventions)
5. Add a single mapping from `/` to `C:/myapp/src/main/webapp` in `$CATALINA_HOME/Catalina/localhost/myapp.xml`

See [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html)

> The default behavior of the War task is to copy the content of src/main/webapp to the root of the archive

Comment: Please see *Update 2*